# o serialVersionUID de tem que ser o mesmo em todas as classes "Serializáveis"?

Tags: java, serialização, desserialização

Eu já tenho alguma noção sobre o serialVersionUID representar a versão da classe (em forma bytes), bem objetivamente.
Mas o número da versão pode ou deve ser o mesmo em diferentes classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser o mesmo ou pode ser diferente conforme explica no link a seguir:

https://blog.caelum.com.br/entendendo-o-serialversionuid/

Por padrão o JDK se encarrega de fazer a validação e geração do serialVersion, porém, em alguns casos, em que você queira controlar a versão da sua .class para que ela seja compatível com versões anteriores, é interessante que você tenha o controle dessa versão. Como é a versão da .class, quer dizer que é uma versão para cada .class, mas não necessariamente não pode ser diferente de outros.

> Como então devemos proceder para escolher um serialVersionUID
>   apropriado? É muito simples: se essa classe está nascendo neste
>   momento, você pode se dar ao luxo de utilizar um serialVersionUID,
>   como por exemplo:

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {   
   private static final
   long serialVersionUID = 1L;   private String login; 
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Gilvan, eu li este artigo tb. Só não tinha ficado explicito que poderia ser igual.